# In ViewController.m, how can I access a property declared in ViewController.h by a string?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, properties

For example, I have, in my ViewController.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonA;
....
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonZ;
```

in my ViewController.m, I have:

```
for (unichar ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++) {
    NSMutableString *nameOfButton = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"button"];
    [nameOfButton appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&ch length:1]];
    //Code equivalent to change "self.(nameOfButton).text = @"";"
}
```

I'm trying to iterate through all of the buttons, and change their text property. Basically, I'm unsure of how to make the above for loop do the equivalent of:

```
self.buttonA.text = @"";
self.buttonB.text = @"";
...
self.buttonZ.text = @"";
```

because I'm using a NSString 'nameOfButton' instead of the actual property name.

Comment: in for loop what nameOfButton look ?? i mean what is display check by NSLOg ??

Comment: The right way to solve this is usually `IBOutletCollection`.

Comment: if someone's answer fixed you issue don't forget to upvote and mark as top answer so others with the same issue will know what solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
for (unichar ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++) {
    NSMutableString *nameOfButton = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"button"];
    [nameOfButton appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&ch length:1]];
    //Code equivalent to change "self.(nameOfButton).text = @"";"
    NSLog(@"%@",nameOfButton);


    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[self valueForKey:nameOfButton];
    [btn setTitle:nameOfButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The code makes all your buttons in this series to change there title to there outlet name.The code with that log is self explanatory

Answer (score 3):

You can make an IBOutlet collection instead of multiple UIButton IBOutlets and loop over the buttons in your outlet collection.
When you make the connection between the view and code you choose outlet collection in the dialog that pops open. (under connection)

Example: call your IBOutlet collection button list and loop over it:

```
for (UIButton *button in self.buttonList) {
    [button setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

PS: Remember to always use set title for state, .text doesn't work on buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can use KVC (key value coding) to pull out properties using strings e.g.

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[self valueForKey@"buttonA"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use KVC (Key-Value Coding) inside your loop:

```
[self setValue:@"" forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.text", nameOfButton]];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through all the buttons in self.view if they are added to the viewcontroller's view  with the following

```
for (UIButton *button in self.view.subviews) {
// your code here

}
```